# Why we can assume this radical extension is a splitting field of some polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $F\subset L\subset M$ where $F\subset L$ is the splitting field of $f\in F[x]$ and $F\subset M$ is radical.

It is said that we can assume $F\subset M$ is a splitting field of some $g\in F[x]$.

Can anyone tell me why?

Furthermore, is it true generally? Namely, for any radical extension $F\subset M$, we can always assume it is a splitting field?

Comment: It is *extremely awkward* to read your question because of the orientation of your notation. Since English goes from left to right, it makes much more sense to say "... where $L\supset F$ is the splitting field of $f\in F[x]$ and $M\supset F$ is radical".

Comment: @ZevChonoles, my notation follows the book Galois Theory written by David A.Cox. At first I'm not used to it too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that what is being claimed is that *you can replace $M$ with a bigger extension $N \supseteq M$* of $F$ such that $N/F$ is still radical, and $N/F$ is a splitting field.

For this, take $N/F$ to be the normal closure of $M/F$. In fact, the normal closure of a radical extension is again radical.

Comment: @hxhxhx88, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The requirement that $L$ be a splitting field of some $f\in F[x]$ implies nothing, unless you say something extra about $f$; otherwise, you could just have $L=F$ with $f=x$. Thus, **every** radical extension $M$ of $F$ contains the splitting field $L$ of some $f\in F[x]$.

For a counterexample to both the initial question and the generalization, take the case of $F=L=\mathbb{Q}$, $M=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, and $f=x$. We have that $L$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $F$, and $M/F$ is a radical extension, but $M$ is not a splitting field of any element of $F[x]$ because it is not a normal extension.

Here is a less trivial example, i.e. one where $L\neq F$: take $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and $M=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$, and $f=x^2-2$. We have that $L$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $F$, and $M/F$ is a radical extension, but $M$ is not a splitting field of any element of $F[x]$ because it is not a normal extension.

Comment: Your counterexample is enlightening. But what I mean is that, for any $L/F$ which is the splitting field of some $f\in F[x]$, can we always find a extension $M\supset L\supset F$ where $M/F$ is radical and the splitting field of some $g\in F[x]$? In your first example, we can let $M=\mathbb{Q}$.